# sh install.sh and script errors

Tags: scripts, sh

I was try to install Parallel Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 and should be install some Sh file. When i used `sh install.sh`, it gave this error:

```
{trap: SIGTSTP: bad trap
Error: Incorrect path to installation script. Installation can not be started
if the path contains space symbols.

Quitting! Press "Enter" to terminate install.
install.sh: 251: read: arg count
install.sh: 252: exit: Illegal number: -1}
```

So what i must be do for this error? thanks

Comment: The Error is "Installation can not be started if the path contains space symbols", so the obvious question: What is the full path to the script? (run `pwd` to see).

Answer (score 0):

Run the installation script from a folder whose name does not contains spaces, and same for any parent folder.

For example, "/home/yourname/Downloads" is okay, "/home/yourname/Downloads/Parallel Studio" is not.

try:

```
mv install.sh /home/yourname/Downloads
cd /home/yourname/Downloads
sh install.sh
```